# Load C# class using PHP

Tags: c#, php, xml

I'm developing an online system in PHP that needs to consult a cloud DB. The provider documentation brings a C# code to access the external data. It brings a XML doc with the query result.

The problem is: I have no idea of how to do this access through the PHP system code, even send the user and password (that needs to be sent as well). I cannot provide the real code, but I made a change to show you how it is.

```
example.consulta.ws wsConsulta = new example.consulta.ws();
string Retorno = wsConsulta.WSCSB("Name","LastName","Age","user","password");
XmlDocument objXML = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode node;
objXML.LoadXml(Retorno);
```

Comment: What did I wrong to get my ask downvoted? :/

Comment: a) You can run exec (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) in PHP to call on other languages using cli but that is not advisable. b) You probably want to create your own PHP class to interface in the same way your `ws` class is. Though without even knowing what the `ws` class nor the `WSCSB` method even does then I doubt anyone here can help.

Comment: Maybe because this has been asked before. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14825009/579895) for example. If that is not what you want, please edit your question and try to explain your problem better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I understand that the other party has exposed a classic SOAP web service to you.

You don't need to use C# code to consume it. It's only provided as a sample. Web services are meant for interoperability.

[Use PHP to consume the web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430/how-to-easily-consume-a-web-service-from-php).

Comment: Thanks @Zesty! I'll read the link content to see if I can understand it.